# Which version of Spring Security is compatible with Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-security, maven-3

Currently I am on

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
```

when i try to move to

```
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
```

I get the following error.

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.6:compile (default) on project services: Compiler errors:
error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=2845 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.codehaus.mojo.aspectj.CompilationFailedException: Compiler errors:
error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.SmartInitializingSingleton
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=2845 AopXmls=#0
```

I am using Spring 4.2.3.RELEASE
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use 3.2.5..it will work

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 4.1.3 of spring-security is compatible with spring 4.2.3 as you can see at maven repository

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks Jens. It works but I am still wondering why is there SmartInitializingSingleton issue with 3.2.1.RELEASE as it is also listed as compatible with the Spring version(spring 4.2.3) i am using.

Comment: @Developer where you find the compatibility informations. The Interface SmartInitializingSingleton is introduced in spring 4.1